If I have a type of an object, how can I use the types of its values?
I have a function for extracting nested GraphQL data:
const data = {
   cats: { edges: [ {node: cat1}, {node: cat2} ] },
   dogs: { edges: [ {node: dog1}, {node: dog2}, {node: dog3} ] },
}

const extracted = extract<{ cats: CatType, dogs: DogType }>(data);

// extracted = {
//   cats: [cat1, cat2], // CatType[]
//   dogs: [dog1, dog2, dog3], // DogType[]
// }

However, I'm having difficulty getting my type signature right.  What I want to say is "This function takes an arg of an interface with string keys and type values, and it returns an object with those same keys, and values of arrays of their corresponding type".
In other words, if the function got { cats: nestedCats } it should return { cats: CatType[] } (ie. cats: T['cat'])). If it got { dogs: nestedDogs } it should return { dogs: DogType[] }, fish { fishes: FishType[] }, and so on.  And if it gets multiple types, it should return an object with arrays of all of them.
Right now I have a signature of:
export const extractNodesFromData = <T extends { [key: string]: any }> =>

However, I have two problems:

A) inside my function, as I iterate through data, how can I refer to that data's type?  For instance:
Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => // How do I type value?
Object.entries(data).map((([key, value: T[key]]) => // Doesn't work

B) I can't specify the function's return type: I can't figure out how to convert my provided type (of { cat: CatType, ...}) into the same thing, but for arrays (ie. { cat: CatType[], ...}) ... which is what the function will actually return.


Full Reproducible Example
This adds nothing to the actual question, but some might find it helpful to see the other (irrelevant) JS/TS:
interface CatType {
   id: string;
   name: string;
   catBreed: string;
}
interface DogType {
   id: string;
   name: string
   dogBreed: string;
}

const extractNodes = <T>(data): T[] =>
    data?.edges?.map(({ node }) => node);

const extractNodesFromData = <T extends { [key: string]: any }> (data: any) => 
Object.entries(data).reduce(
    (extracted, [key, value: T[key]]) => ({
      ...extracted,
      [key]: extractNodes<T[key]>(value)
    }),
    {}
  )


• Please [edit] to provide a [mre] where all your types and values are declared for us. That will allow us to get started on writing a solution without first having to try to guess what CatType, cat1, etc should look like. • You have two problems but you should be asking about one of them per question post. Please [edit] to make sure that you are asking just one question. • Are you possibly asking this question? If so, we can close this one as a duplicate; if not, please [edit] to distinguish them clearly.

The question has all necessary information.  I could add a JS function's code to it, but that wouldn't add anything meaningful at all, because this isn't a code question, it's a question of how to use Typescript.  The function's code is completely independent from how to access a property of a provided type (ie. what the question is asking), so adding it would just add more noise, not more signal.

If you won't provide a [mre] I'll disengage. Good luck.

Repro added.  As you can see, it does nothing to help explain the question (it's just irrelevant JS; the relevant parts are the JS/TS above it).

CatType and cat1 etc are still not provided. Would you mind going back to my first comment, reading it carefully, and responding to each piece? Otherwise I'm likely to repeat myself.

sigh Added, but again they are completely meaningless: it doesn't matter whether CatType has a hundred string properties, twenty object properties, or no properties at all: the question is exactly the same regardless.  The question has nothing to do with CatType ... again, the question is how do I extract CatType or any other type in existence from an object that maps strings to those types).  Polluting a question with info that has nothing to do with the question only makes it harder to answer, not easier, because the answerer has to page in all that (again, not relevant) info.

If it's too much trouble for you to comply with my requests then I really don't have to bother you. Maybe someone else will come and look? I certainly don't enjoy the feeling that I'm annoying you by trying to engage.

I'm always happy to provide all relevant information on every question I've ever asked here on Stack Overflow.  I do find it annoying however when people insist on me adding information that has nothing to do with the question that I'm asking, and I think it's legitimate to feel that way.  What CatType is truly has nothing whatsoever to do with the basic TS question I'm asking, so I don't see how you're making it better for you, me, or anyone else to include that info.

You are not being kind and I can't understand why. Surely you don't expect everyone to view things exactly from your perspective. Do you truly think I don't consider the information I'm requesting to be relevant? Or that you are the sole arbiter of what makes a question good? I am honestly trying to engage in a way that will result in a solution to a question and that future readers will find useful. Right now I've got something like this code but frankly I'm apprehensive about continuing here at all, because I expect to be scolded instead of engaged with.

In what way was anything I said unkind?  What you are asking for was irrelevant:  CatType had nothing whatsoever to do with the answer. Look, I've answered over 700 questions here, and not once did I ever ask the questioner for info that I didn't actually need to answer the question.  When you do, it doesn't help anything: your comments made it less likely that this question will receive an answer than if you had simply said nothing.  I do find that frustrating, because I believe SO is here to help us help each other, and it's frustrating when someone instead decides to obstruct.

A [mre] is not irrelevant. This approach might be what you’re looking for? If so let me know and I’ll post an answer. If not then let me know and I’ll delete my comments so you can hopefully have the interactions you’re more comfortable with.

"I do find it annoying however when people insist on me adding information that has nothing to do with the question that I'm asking". Most people can't run the code in their heads. To help you we need to run the code ourselves, see the type errors, poke it here and there, see what happens, interrogate what type is being inferred at what point, etc. To that end, the minimal requirements that make a snippet of code work are highly relevant. Even if it's not relevant to the problem, it's relevant in replicating the problem. It helps us help you.

Alex, that makes total sense, but there are different types of questions right?  Some are "help me make this code work" questions, and those 100% require a repro.  But if I just ask "how do I split based on commas in Javascript", the person answering doesn't need a "repro example" (of a string with commas in it) to tell me "use the split method" ... right?  Same idea here: my question here wasn't about any specific Javascript code, it was about how one could use Typescript to do something (use a property of a type), generally.  The code was just to help explain, it wasn't the question.

The answer you got, contains the supporting lines that you were reluctant to add (CatType/DogType), and more (cat/dog vars) which jcalz had to create for you. And it's presence there helps prove that the solution works as expected with the input data/types you are expecting to work. So when you characterize someone asking for that stuff as "decides to obstruct", that feels bad. If you are asking strangers on the internet for help, it helps to make a good faith effort to make it as easy as possible for them to help you. Last I'll reply here, but you're in good hands now. Good luck :)

The answer I got, extracted from an entire sandbox of code, was "use the [K in keyof T] syntax".  I was looking for that and related info, not a sandbox, and (hindsight being 20/20) it would have been easier to just say that, I'd think.  None of my effort providing further info, repro, etc. helped provide that, nor did JCalz's sandbox help him explain it.  I would hav  preferred that he had just read my question and offered a simple answer, rather than put in all that extra wasted effort making me provide repros and such.

Oof, this continues to feel bad. I can see the multiple comments you’ve written and deleted and it’s quite unpleasant. I don’t understand why I would need to justify asking for a [mre] further. We don’t agree on what constitutes relevance or obstruction and it’s unlikely that we will agree after further discussion. So could we just… leave it there? I’m actually beginning to dread seeing these inbox notifications. So, truce? Please?

Look, I got my answer and was happy with it ... then @Alex Wayne had to chime in with the "see, weren't you wrong from the start?" comment. I felt I should correct them and explain that the answer wasn't derived from the comment thread.  It was in no way directed at you (again, I appreciate your answer ... I just felt we could have gotten to it without this comment thread, or the sandbox code).  There's absolutely no need for any further conversation; truce accepted, and I await your answer, so that I can properly credit you.

I would give extractNodesFromData the following call signature:
declare const extractNodesFromData: <T extends object>(
  data: { [K in keyof T]: { edges: { node: T[K] }[] } }
) => { [K in keyof T]: T[K][] }

The function is generic in T, an object-like type that maps keys to node types.  (The constraint of the object type isn't super important; you could relax it to {} or leave it as {[k: string]: any} or even just use unknown or leave it unconstrained.  The object type is mostly just for semantics: it's a key-value mapping and isn't meant to be a primitive type.) For your example, that would look like { cats: CatType, dogs: DogType }.
Then the type of the data parameter is a mapped type over the properties in T; for every property in T with a key of type K and a value of the indexed access type T[K], the corresponding property in data keys of T, the corresponding property of data at key K has a value of type { edges: { node: T[K] }[] }. The intent here is that when you call extractNodesFromData(data), TypeScript should be able to infer T from the type of data. This works because the mapped type is homomorphic (see What does "homomorphic mapped type" mean?), and TypeScript is set up to be able to make such inferences from homomorphic mapped types.  If data is of type { cats: { edges: { node: CatType }[] }, dogs: { edges: { node: DogType }[] } } then T should be inferred as type { cats: CatType, dog: DogType }
The return type is a mapped type of the form { [K in keyof T]: T[K][] }, so each property of T, with a key of type K and a value of type T[K], becomes a property of the output with a key K and a value T[K][]; essentially wrapping all the properties with an array type.  So if T is { cats: CatType, dog: DogType } then the return type is { cats: CatType[], dog: DogType[] }
Let's make sure that works with an example:
const cat1: CatType = { id: "c1", name: "c1", catBreed: "c1" };
const cat2: CatType = { id: "c2", name: "c2", catBreed: "c2" };
const dog1: DogType = { id: "d1", name: "d1", dogBreed: "d1" };
const dog2: DogType = { id: "d2", name: "d2", dogBreed: "d2" };
const dog3: DogType = { id: "d3", name: "d3", dogBreed: "d3" };
const data = {
  cats: { edges: [{ node: cat1 }, { node: cat2 }] },
  dogs: { edges: [{ node: dog1 }, { node: dog2 }, { node: dog3 }] },
}

const extracted = extractNodesFromData(data);
// const extracted: { cats: CatType[], dogs: DogType[] }

Looks good.

Now, as for the implementation of extractNodesFromData, you'll end up needing to use type assertions or the like to loosen the type checking and get the compiler not to complain.
The TypeScript type checker really can't do too much verification of generic type manipulation except for very basic indexing. It certainly doesn't know how the output of the Object.entries() method relates to that mapped type; see Preserve Type when using Object.entries.  And it can't see how the reduce() method will build up from an empty object to a value of the expected type. See Typing a reduce over a Typescript tuple for a similar issue. It's just not something the compiler can follow.
So the easiest approach is to pepper it with type assertions until it stops reporting errors, such as:
const extractNodesFromData = <T extends object>(
  data: { [K in keyof T]: { edges: { node: T[K] }[] } }) =>
  Object.entries(data).reduce(
    (extracted, [key, value]) => ({
      ...extracted,
      [key]: extractNodes(value as any)
    }),
    {}
  ) as { [K in keyof T]: T[K][] }

where we just assert the return type and I even throw a value as any assertion in there, to relieve the compiler from having to verify that value will be the right shape for extractNodes(); the any type is effectively an escape hatch for type checking.
Since the compiler isn't really checking the implementation for you, it means you need to be especially careful that it works as desired.  One quick check is to see that extracted's behavior at runtime is appropriate for the type TypeScript inferred for it:
console.log(extracted.cats.map(c => c.name)) // [LOG]: ["c1", "c2"] 
console.log(extracted.dogs.map(d => d.dogBreed)) // [LOG]: ["d1", "d2", "d3"] 

Looks good at first glance. But the best practice for code like this is to subject it to a wide range of use cases and make sure that it behaves acceptably.
Playground link to code
